# How do I format IRIS data set for input to SVM-Light library?

Tags: python, machine-learning, classification, svmlight

I'm trying to use the [SVM-Light library](http://svmlight.joachims.org/) for training and classification of the IRIS dataset. [Here](http://daoudclarke.github.io/pysvmlight/) is the python wrapper that I'm using. I'm currently following the example on the page but I'm not sure how to format the IRIS data correctly for input. A sample row in the IRIS datset looks like `5.0,3.6,1.4,0.2,Iris-setosa`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know your library, but i highly recommend using [scikit-learn](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/index.html), a powerful general-purpose ML-lib. I suppose you got a good reason to use svmlight, otherwise, libsvm- or liblinear-based usage is much much easier with sklearn (fully automatic; not file-based and automatic multi-class and co.).

Here is some simple example. Keep in mind, that only binary-targets are supported imho, and if you need multi-class learning, you would use sklearn's [multiclass tools](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/classes.html#module-sklearn.multiclass).

#### Code to load and prepare Iris

```
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
from sklearn.datasets import dump_svmlight_file

iris = load_iris()
X = iris.data
y = iris.target

""" only keep first two classes """
indices = y<=1
X = X[indices]
y = y[indices]

""" transform to +1 / -1 targets (0 -> -1) """
y[y==0] = -1

dump_svmlight_file(X, y, 'my_dataset', zero_based=False)  # 1-based!!!
```

#### svmlight call

```
./svm_learn my_dataset my_output -v3
Scanning examples...done
Reading examples into memory...100..OK. (100 examples read)
Setting default regularization parameter C=0.0199
Optimizing...............done. (16 iterations)
Optimization finished (0 misclassified, maxdiff=0.00057).
Runtime in cpu-seconds: 0.00
Number of SV: 32 (including 28 at upper bound)
L1 loss: loss=4.89469
Norm of weight vector: |w|=0.69732
Norm of longest example vector: |x|=9.13674
Estimated VCdim of classifier: VCdim<=31.50739
Computing XiAlpha-estimates...done
Runtime for XiAlpha-estimates in cpu-seconds: 0.00
XiAlpha-estimate of the error: error<=30.00% (rho=1.00,depth=0)
XiAlpha-estimate of the recall: recall=>70.00% (rho=1.00,depth=0)
XiAlpha-estimate of the precision: precision=>70.00% (rho=1.00,depth=0)
Number of kernel evaluations: 1291
Writing model file...done
```